# Php grpc not supporting concurrent calls

Tags: php, grpc

I have implemented grpc for my php microservices for faster API request.
I am summarizing the problem as below
Let's say there are 2 microservices m1 and m2
and the grpc calls start from m1
So, initially m1 makes a grpc call to m2, again to resolve the dependency related to m1,
m2 makes a call to m1 but as there is one more dependency for this request to close with m2,
So, again m1 makes a call to m2 but at this point the request gets stuck.

m1 ----------> m2

m1 <---------- m2

m1 ------x---> m2 (this call is not happening, request is stuck here)

the above depicted call is the same call initiated by m1.

Note: On both the microservices m1 and m2 grpc server is running and it's on the same port.

I am unable to figure out why the call is stuck here.
On research I found that grpc doesn't support concurrent calls, but is it that grpc has the limitation?

Request the developers help here.

Thanks

I tried searching for results and didn't find much help regarding my use case.
and found this **https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12175**, but couldn't relate much.

Comment: If you explain more what you're trying to do (why you need multiple calls), we might be able to see if there is a better way. I always get chills when two microservices are calling each other like that. More often than not, it means that you're not really using microservices as intended, but rather have a distributed monolith (which tend to end up being a hard-to-debug mess).

Comment: What are you using to front the PHP GRPC service? Are you simply running `php -S`?

Comment: I didn't get u @Sammitch, can u pls elaborate a little more

Comment: `php -S` is a _single threaded_ web server for limited testing purposes, it can not service more than a single request concurrently.

Comment: I was running the server this way php /path/to/entry/script.php GRPCServer, I didn't check for concurrent requests from same source but I guess the requests from different sources should support

Comment: But as @M.Eriksson said, this would not look different from a Monolith approach, I am looking for a way much better for my microservice. For ex: I am looking for a way where I can get the data from different source points more easily instead of doing multiple calls. It should be like single getter point for each source point for any kind of data and there should not be multiple calls for a single target. If anyone can help in kind would be greatful

Comment: @Sammitch if you have any kind of knowledge on stable microservices in php then pls do share your points also, it would be helpful, Thanks